# How to make autocomplete shows results in specific order?

Tags: jquery

I'm referring to this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/dryydaxq/1/

If I type Eng in the texbox,I see the list in following order in the autocomplete list.

1) **Eng**lish
2) Guzh**eng**
3) Chemical **Eng**ineering
4) #mechanical **eng**ineering

How do I make the above list arranged in a order where those phrases starting with 'eng' shows above the rest? Like below, English shown first as it starts with eng, then chemical and mechanical engineering as 'eng' in the middle while guzheng last.

1) **Eng**lish
2) Chemical **Eng**ineering
3) #mechanical **eng**ineering
4) Guzh**eng**

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a comparison function to `.sort()` in JavaScript.

I've edited your [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dryydaxq/6/) and it now sorts the dropdown correctly.

I added:

```
$('#search').on('keydown', function() {
    colors = colors.sort(function(a,b) {

           return a[1].indexOf($('#search').val()) > b[1].indexOf($('#search').val());

    })       
});
```

Although please note that this sorts on the position of 'eng' in the entire phrase, not individual words. If you need to sort on words then you could tokenize the strings in the `sort` function on the space character and then calculate your value from there.

Comment: but the output order is same with the original

Comment: I've added an event into the code to sort the array on each keypress, please have a look now.